# Expanding fields not working fully on SharePoint Lists

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am following the documentation for [Get metadata for a list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/list_get).

Querying using either PowerShell or the Graph Explorer fails to fully expand the fields for items in a SharePoint list.

An example of this is a lookup field called `Responsible` that looks up users in Azure Active Directory (or in SharePoint terms, the column is a `Person or Group` column, limited to people only).

Once selected via the GUI, it's populated with a display name (although I'd hope for more definitive information to be stored on the back end, like `UPN`).

When querying the Graph API using the form:

```ps
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$($SPSite.id)/lists/$($ServiceList.id)/items?expand=fields"
$Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accesstoken"} -Uri $Uri -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop
```

we get something like this:

```ps
@odata.etag               : "REMOVED"
Title                     : Storage Platform
Description               : Central storage platform
ResponsibleLookupId       : 14
Responsible2LookupId      : 13
AccountableLookupId       : 3
Features                  : NFS
AudienceLookupId          : 92
RequestProcess            : {@{LookupId=1; LookupValue=Service Desk}}
Support                   : {@{LookupId=1; LookupValue=Service Desk}}
AvailabilityLookupId      : 1
DependsOn                 : {}
O365GroupLookupId         : 87
LifecycleStageLookupId    : 2
ConsultLookupId           : 88
id                        : 1
ContentType               : Item
Modified                  : 2017-11-17T10:47:07Z
Created                   : 2017-11-17T10:47:07Z
_UIVersionString          : 1.0
Attachments               : False
Edit                      : 
LinkTitleNoMenu           : Storage Platform
LinkTitle                 : Storage Platform
ItemChildCount            : 0
FolderChildCount          : 0
_ComplianceFlags          : 
_ComplianceTag            : 
_ComplianceTagWrittenTime : 
_ComplianceTagUserId      :
```

You can see that the field `ResponsibleLookupId` just gives a value of `14` which is not useful. Other fields link to Office 365 Groups, but again return values. As such it's impossible to link any of this data to users/groups and is very limited in value except when looking at it through the portal.

How do we expand this data? Will it be provided by the API call at a later date, or do we have to perform further look ups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Microsoft Graph will return the `LookupId` for lookup fields. You can ask it to provide the actual value by specifically requesting that field in a `$select` parameter.

Using the following query will return the `displayName` rather than the `LookupId` for `Responsible`:

```
...items?expand=fields($select=Responsible)
```

You can read about how this works in the documentation for [FieldValueSet](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/fieldvalueset).

As for returning the `userPrincipalName`, currently you can't control which value it returns (it's either `LookupId` or `displayName`).I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you - this works. I had naively assumed that expand=fields should expand all fields, and that the addition of ($select=) on the end would merely refine that list (much like piping to `Select-Object` in PowerShell would do). We can force the selection/storage(?) of email in the field instead of displayname, which is more unique / usable. It's a shame about the maximum lookup of 12 fields however. I'll head over to UserVoice.

Comment: I agree, the email address is a better option but unfortunately folks don't always have control over the default. Would be nice if you could ask for ResponsibleExpanded and get the full object instead of just one or the other. As for the 12, I had the same reaction when I first started working with it. In practice I found I rarely ran into the limitation since 12 fields is a lot to surface from a collection at one time.